# Rename [printer-scanner] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request, tag-cleanup-request

Suggest broadening the [printer-scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-scanner) tag to [multifunction-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multifunction-printer).  Many of these devices include fax and the more generic term would be a logical one that wouldn't cause confusion.  There is an existing [fax](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fax) tag, but it doesn't hurt to have overlap.  Questions about faxing on a multifunction printer appear under both tags.  An alternative would be to create a synonym tag.

Comment: Whenever someone says "printer scanner" I say "why would you need to scan a printer?".

Comment: You say that every time?

Comment: Yes, but the subject doesn't come up very often in my circles so I rarely get to use the joke :(

Comment: Do you think that maybe the multifunction-printer tag would be **too broad**? It would be Copying, Printing, Scanning **and** Faxing then?

Comment: IMHO, no.  It already includes printing, scanning and copying, so including fax doesn't change the nature of the category.  People already assume the term refers to all multi-function printers and use it that way.  There are separate tags for each function if the question is function-specific.  Multi-function printers can have issues related to the multi-functionality, like driver bundles or not being able to scan or fax because one ink color is empty.